# How to check linear independence

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, regression

How can I check the linear independence of my variables?

I have this system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a $N \times 4$ matrix.

I want to check the linear independence between the 4 variables in matrix $A$.

Comment: How about Gaussian elimination?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "linear independence between the 4 variables".

Comment: Or how about checking the determinant? Just a different approach...

Comment: If $N$ is not 4, determinant is not defined. Rank can be checked for the same purpose.

Comment: He should re-edit to say "... check linear independence of the rows."

Comment: I mean linear independence of the rows of matrix $A$. $N$ is not 4 is a large number 30001.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "linear independence between the 4 variables". If you want the solution to be unique, the rank of both $A$ and $[A|b]$ needs to be $4$.